# Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() but mysqlnd seems installed

Tags: php, mysqli

I am getting

> Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result()

for the below php code at line `$result = $stmt->get_result()`. I am using laravel framework for this project;

```
   $conn = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $db);
   $stmt = $conn->prepare("select name from user where username=?");
   $stmt->bind_param("s", "username");
   $stmt->execute();
   $result = $stmt->get_result();
```

PHP version is 5.4.43.

Below are the settings I found from `phpinfo()`.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mysqli ext is built without mysqlnd support as it's absent in "API Extensions" and "Client API library version". It seems you need to recompile mysqli, or - better - just re-install it using packet manager.

Comment: what do you mean by `recompile mysqli, or - better - just re-install it using packet manager` ? sorry am a newbie.